# Is there a way to open a website and press the play button using python?

Tags: python, macos, browser

I want to record my favorite radio channel on a website in safari that plays every evening. Now unfortunately the website has changed and doesn't play the podcast automatically, now you have to press the play button. Is there a way to code so it plays the audio by itself?

i have tried the web browser function, but this only opens the link, and does not play the audio.

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('http://google.de', new=2)
```

Comment: What you need may be [Selenium](https://google.com/search?q=selenium).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible , you can use the selenium module.

You can find more about it here: https://pypi.org/project/selenium/